# The probability of "7.5 births per minute"

Tags: probability

In 2012, there were [3,952,841 births within the US](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/births.htm). Also, in 2012, there were $366 \times 24 \times 60 = 527040$ minutes in the year. This results in an average of 
$$\frac {3952841} {527040} \approx 7.5000$$ births per minute.

However, intuitively I would expect that it would be highly unlikely that there were precisely 8 seconds between each birth that happened within the year. Instead, there would have been random time intervals between each birth, some quite short (two babies born at exactly the same time) and some much longer.

I have two questions:

1. What is the probability that all time intervals between births were equal? Obviously this will be a very small but non-zero number.
2. What is the probability that there was at least one birth within every minute of the year? I would expect this to be larger, but not 1.

Let's assume birth timing is purely random (no effects due to time of day etc.) to simplify the question a bit.

Comment: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~marchini/teaching/L5/L5.notes.pdf . See the examples section

Comment: The answer to question #1 depends on you time-resolution. If it's discrete (for examples, the smallest time unit is $1$ millisecond), then you can calculate a probability larger than $0$ (and indeed very small). If it is continuous (non-discrete), then the probability is $0$, because you have a single sample where all intervals were equal, and an infinite amount of other samples within the sample-space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea for your second question.

If we let $X$ be the number of births in any given minute of the year, we should get a good approximation by saying $X$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda=7.500$.  Then probability of at least one birth in the minute $=P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-7.500}\approx .999447$.

Then the probability of a birth in every single minute of the year should be approximately $(1-e^(-7.500))^{527040}$ which seems to be on the order of $10^{-126}$.

It looks like a pretty safe bet that some minute during the year will have no births.